# Is every continous function in $\mathbb{R}^3$ a surface?

Tags: surfaces

there is a knot in my brain. Assume some Datapoints in $\mathbb{R}^3$. I want to fit a surface through them. I found a lot of surfaces such as multiple quadric surfaces (so dont worry that i haven't googled it). I have the following questions:

1. Is it correct to say, that a plane is a surface? equation: $0=ax+by+cz+d$
2. Isnt $z=ax^2+by^2$ a surface as well?
3. Is each other polynomial e.g. $z=ax+by+cx^2+dy^2+ex^3+fy^3$ as well a surface? In that case a cubic? When I google cubic surfaces, I get some really strange one.

I would appreciate any hints which clear my mind.

Horsti

Comment: How do you define surface?

Comment: Most of the time, yes. There are some extreme cases: $x^2+y^2+z^2 =0$ has only a point, $x^2+y^2 = 0$ is a line.

Comment: Thank you, that helped :)